# Silverlight: branding/design and navigation

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, navigation, branding

I have some years exprience with **ASP.NET**, but I am new to **Silverlight**. 
I have a basic question regarding  the design and navigation of a Silverlight page/application ?  If a Silverlight project is hosted together with an ASP.NET project,
is it possible to use **masterpages** for the **branding/design** and **navigation** for the page/application ? Has Silverlight a similar / analogue concept like masterpages ?

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight works like flash applications do. If you create a Silverlight only application that covers the whole screen, then masterpages do not apply. You would need to use Silverlight code to achieve the same thing.

If you use it as an embedded object, then you can use masterpages for the rest of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does have kind of the same concept as master pages. The navigation framework plays this role. There is usually a MainPage with a "Frame". This is the area that other "Views" would have their content placed in.

To give a bit more detail...

The MainPage navigation Frame can be surrounded by menus, banners, branding, etc. The Frame area is filled by each Silverlight Page that you navigate to. These navigation "Pages" contain the data entry forms, grids, etc. that represent your content.